# Starting error with laravel 4 : Whoops! There was an error

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I was installing laravel 4 by following steps in the official website laravel.com
i downloaded the 4' version from github then i've running the command :

```
php composer.phar install
```

but when i try to start laravel by opening the path localhost/laravel/public
it show me this error

[image]

Can you help me?
thank you

Comment: Did you receive any errors during install? Does anything change if you run `php composer.phar update`?

Comment: What happens if you try to open localhost/laravel/ ? The localhost/laravel/public path is not reachable anyway. The problem could come from your server, do you use LAMP, Apache ? Your server has to point to your laravel/public path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear your cookies for 'localhost' and try again - this is likely picking up a session ID from a previous project.  Even better would be to setup a Virtual Host so that you're not working from "localhost" but instead a domain like "mysite.dev".